# Cloud Shell docker support

Tags: azure-cloud-shell

Will docker be supported in the Cloud Shell?  Today, if you attempt to use docker, such as "docker login " or even "az acr login -n MyRegistry", you get an error saying that the docker service isn't running:

Warning: failed to get default registry endpoint from daemon (Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?). Using system default: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Answer (score 1):

Docker daemon likely won't be supported. The recommendation is to use your remote docker machine. Cloud Shell has docker-machine tool pre-installed for you to create & manage your remote Docker VM.

Comment: Can you explain how I would do this?